# Identifying hidden characters in text

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, character, removing-whitespace

I have an ETL process that regularly extracts code from an ODBC data source, manipulates it, and inserts it into my postgres database. One of the columns from this data source regularly has odd characters in it.

For the most part I can catch and convert all of the characters appropriately, but I have one character that exists in the ODBC data source, cannot be brought into postgres (all of the text after that character gets truncated), and I'm having a hard time identifying what the character is.

I can't even insert an example of the character directly into this post because it gets stripped out :/ The closest I can get is a screen shot of the character in textmate (the only application I can actually see the character in):

[image: unknown character]

There character is the diamond between the 1 and 0. When my data comes in, everything after the 0 is truncated.

Is there a good way of identifying what this character is so I can figure out a way of stripping it out?

Comment: Save it to a text file and generate a hex dump of the file. Add it here if it still isn't clear.

Comment: "Everything after the 0 is truncated", do you mean after the 1?

Comment: @tripleee, yes sorry I meant after the 1. Good idea on the hex dump. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @triplee, A hex dump shows the character as a hex null value (00). That allowed me to move forward. Do you want to answer the question so I can give you credit for it? Also, thank you! :)

Comment: Nah, feel free to answer it yourself, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per tripleee's comment on the original question post:

To identify the character I grabbed the hex value of the text to identify the hex value of the  offending character in question.

There are a number of ways to do this, but the quickest way for me was to use a utility application I have called [HexFiend](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/HexFiend/) so dump the text into. Once the text was in and I highlighted the character it returned the hex value "00".

A bit more investigation pointed towards the hex null value being used as a line terminator in  C applications (which makes sense given the context of my project).

I've fit this null value into my ETL process so that it gets switched out with a new line and now everything is sunshine and daises.

Thanks again for the help!